# Allowing enum to be null in Avro schema

Tags: json, apache-kafka, schema, avro

In my Avro schema, I have a field called `myenum` of type `enum` as follows:

```
{
"name": "myenum",
    "type": {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "Suit",
        "symbols": ["SPADES", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS"]
    }
}
```

I also want `null` to be allowed. If I change the type to be a union with the default value as `null` (as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283736/avro-enum-field)), it looks like this:

```
{
"name": "myenum",
    "type": ["null", {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "Suit",
        "symbols": ["SPADES", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS"]
    }]
}
```

When I test it with the following JSON object `{"myenum":"HEARTS"}`, I get an error - `Expected start-union. Got VALUE_STRING`.

If I test it with a null value `{"myenum": null}`, it works. How can I make an enum field optional?

Answer (score 0):

For Avro's JSON encoding, you need to pass the intended type for every non-null union value.

```
{"myenum": {"string": "HEARTS"}}
```

should do the trick for you.

Comment: I tried that too, after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485580/how-to-fix-expected-start-union-got-value-number-int-when-converting-json-to-av). However, when I do this, I get an error: `Unknown union branch string`.

Comment: Did you include a namespace?

Comment: I did not, which I suspect is the issue. I'm trying to wrap my head around namespaces. If I have the schema defined like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50294844/7124380), to include a namespace as you've suggested, do I have to change the JSON encoding of the object or the schema itself?

Comment: @WarrenCrasta See my updated answer and let me know if this has worked for you.

Comment: Tried and I get an error: `org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: "record" is not a defined name. The type of the "Test" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...} expression.`

Comment: Could I change my JSON encoding to be this? `{ "com.abc.Suit": { "myenum": { "string": "HEARTS" } } }`

Comment: @WarrenCrasta Did you try it? It might work for your initial schema.

Comment: I tried changing the JSON encoding. I got the error `Expected start-union. Got END_OBJECT`. Oh well, thanks for your help. I guess I'll have to keep messing around with this more, but I also think it's a namespace issue.

Comment: If you have a namespace `com.abc` defined on your Schema, it should be more something like `{ "myenum": {"com.abc.Suit": "HEARTS" } }`