# Avro ENUM field: Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected start-union. Got VALUE_STRING

Tags: java, avro

I am working on a schema.avsc file, which need to have a enum field and it's optional. My partial avsc schema is like this:

```
{
      "name": "StrategyType",
      "type": ["null", {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "StrategyType",
        "symbols": ["TYPE_A", "TYPE_B"]
      }]
    }
```

however, when I try to use confluent-7.3.2 producer to produce a sample message like this:

```
{
    ...,
    "StrategyType": "TYPE_A"
}
```

or

```
{
        ...,
        "StrategyType": {"enum" : "TYPE_A"}
    }
```

or

```
{
        ...,
        "StrategyType": {"string" : "TYPE_A"}
    }
```

or in [Avro ENUM field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283736/avro-enum-field) which added the name space, like this (it worked once, but now failed again):

```
"StrategyType": {
        "com.namespace.StrategyType": "TYPE_A"
    }
```

It all throw errors:

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected start-union. Got VALUE_STRING
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.error(JsonDecoder.java:511)
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.readIndex(JsonDecoder.java:430)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:282)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:188)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:260)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:248)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:154)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchemaUtils.toObject(AvroSchemaUtils.java:214)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageReader.readFrom(AvroMessageReader.java:124)
```

If I put StrategyType is null, it works. Any ideas, how to fix this issue? Thanks a lot in advanced!